# Delete two columns if right value is zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns. The first column contains the code and the second column contains the null values (0).

Is there a way that I can delete these 2 columns, if the second column value is equal to zero?

[image: Here is the needed result]

I tried using this, but it only deletes the zero values in the second column.

```
Sub ClearZero()
    For Each cell In Range("C6:D4005")
        If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
Sub ClearZero()

For Each cell In Range("D6:D4005")
 If cell.Value = "0" Then 
    cell.Clear
    cell.offset(0, -1).Clear
 End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Correction - use `For Each cell In Range("D6:D4005")`, because otherwise if a cell in C column evaluates to 0 then it will delete a cell from B column. And even if that's never going to happen in this dataset it's worth thinking about, plus it would halve the length of the loop.

Comment: thanks @SpencerBarnes, very good point. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve what you want without looping.

**LOGIC:**

1. Identify the worksheet you are going to work with.
2. Remove any autofilter.
3. Check if the column `D` has `0` anywhere.
4. [Find last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) in column `D`. Better than **hardcoding** `D4005`
5. Construct your range.
6. Filter column `D` based on `0`.
7. Identify the filtered range.
8. Clear the cells in 2 columns without looping.

**CODE:**

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it but if you do them simply ask :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim FilteredRange As Range
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Check if the column D has 0 anywhere
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("D1:D" & lRow), 0) Then
           '~~> Filter column D on 0
           .Range("D1:D" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=0
            
            '~~> Identify your range
            Set FilteredRange = .AutoFilter.Range
            
            '~~> Clear the range in 1 go!
            FilteredRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(FilteredRange.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
            FilteredRange.Offset(1, -1).Resize(FilteredRange.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
        End If
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]